# Is there a readymade built Oauth2.so module which is built on linux machine which i can directly load on apache webserver

Tags: linux, apache, unix, oauth-2.0, webserver

Is there a readymade built Oauth2.so module along with dependencies which is built on linux machine which i can directly load in apache webserver